# How do efficiently replace node values depending on some conditions of sub nodes?

Tags: jq

The following json is extracted from a json file in CycloneDX format produced by Syft tool over a debian:bulleye-slim docker image.

```
{
    "bomFormat": "CycloneDX",
    "components": [{
            "name": "bsdutils",
            "version": "1:2.36.1-8+deb11u1",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/bsdutils@1:2.36.1-8+deb11u1?arch=amd64&upstream=util-linux%402.36.1-8+deb11u1&distro=debian-11",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:source",
                    "value": "util-linux"
                }, {
                    "name": "syft:metadata:sourceVersion",
                    "value": "2.36.1-8+deb11u1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "curl",
            "version": "7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/curl@7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7?arch=amd64&distro=debian-11"
        }, {
            "name": "libaudit-common",
            "version": "1:3.0-2",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/libaudit-common@1:3.0-2?arch=all&upstream=audit&distro=debian-11",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:source",
                    "value": "audit"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to transform it as the following, using linux script (on a yaml pipeline):

```
{
    "bomFormat": "CycloneDX",
    "components": [{
            "name": "util-linux",
            "version": "2.36.1-8+deb11u1",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/util-linux@2.36.1-8+deb11u1?arch=source",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:source",
                    "value": "util-linux"
                }, {
                    "name": "syft:metadata:sourceVersion",
                    "value": "2.36.1-8+deb11u1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "curl",
            "version": "7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/curl@7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7?arch=amd64&distro=debian-11"
        }, {
            "name": "audit",
            "version": "1:3.0-2",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/audit@1:3.0-2?arch=source",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:source",
                    "value": "audit"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The pseudo algorithm to make the transformation is:

```
for each component where component.purl.startwith(pkg:deb/debian/) and component.properties.syft:metadata:source is set
   component.name = properties.where(name=="syft:metadata:source").value
   if (properties.syft:metadata:sourceVersion)
       component.version = properties.where(name=="syft:metadata:sourceVersion").value
   component.purl=pkg:deb/debian/{component.name}@{component.version}?arch=source
take any other component not matching the where/select "as is"
```

I thought jq may be the best tool to do the job, but I once again struggle to use it properly.

After some tries with jqplay.org
the fist line (the select part) is given by

```
.components[]|select((.properties[].name=="syft:metadata:source") and (.purl | startswith("pkg:deb/debian")))
```

I now need to combine all to be able to edit the 3 fields I want: name, version and purl from the edited name and version.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Does only source but no version keep the version from the component? What should happen if only version is set, but no source?

Comment: in my current analysis from syft output generating the CycloneDX sBOM, sourceVersion property was only set when source was set too. So the use case of only sourceVersion does not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to interpret your "properties" array as an object and then merge it into the parent while renaming some keys. The following jq program should do that:

```
(.components[] | select(.properties|from_entries?|has("syft:metadata:source")))
|= . + (
    .properties // []
    | from_entries
    | {
        name: ."syft:metadata:source",
        version: ."syft:metadata:sourceVersion"
    }
    | . + { purl: "pkg:deb/debian/\(.name)@\(.version)?arch=source" }
)
```

or the equivalent:

```
"syft:metadata:source" as $source
| "syft:metadata:sourceVersion" as $version
| (.components[] | select(.properties|from_entries?|has($source)))
|= . + (
    .properties // []
    | from_entries
    | {
        name: .[$source],
        version: .[$version],
        purl: "pkg:deb/debian/\(.[$source])@\(.[$version])?arch=source"
    }
)
```

The output for either program will be:

```json
{
  "bomFormat": "CycloneDX",
  "components": [
    {
      "name": "util-linux",
      "version": "2.36.1-8+deb11u1",
      "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/util-linux@2.36.1-8+deb11u1?arch=source",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "syft:metadata:source",
          "value": "util-linux"
        },
        {
          "name": "syft:metadata:sourceVersion",
          "value": "2.36.1-8+deb11u1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "curl",
      "version": "7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7",
      "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/curl@7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7?arch=amd64&distro=debian-11"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you are like me and feel uneasy about the repeated check for the source, then a little restructuring helps to get rid of the repetition:

```
"syft:metadata:source" as $source
| "syft:metadata:sourceVersion" as $version
| .components[]
|= . + (
    (
        .properties//[]
        | from_entries
        | select(has($source))
        | {
            name: .[$source],
            version: .[$version],
            purl: "pkg:deb/debian/\(.[$source])@\(.[$version])?arch=source"
        }
    ) // {}
)
```

To only update the source/name, but skip the version if it is not contained in the properties, use the updated version:

```
"syft:metadata:source" as $syftSource
| "syft:metadata:sourceVersion" as $syftVersion
| .components[]
|= . + (
     (
        .version as $componentVersion
        | .properties//[]
        | from_entries
        | select(has($syftSource))
        | (.[$syftVersion]//$componentVersion) as $version
        | .[$syftSource] as $name
        | {
            $name,
            $version,
            purl: "pkg:deb/debian/\($name)@\($version)?arch=source"
        }
    ) // {}
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Sounds promising!
I however don't get yet the result with jqplay.org. It is complaining with 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting '|' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: "syft:metadata:source" as $source

Comment: @EricBDev odd, it works for me. Try deleting a character and re-adding it. I think I observed this jqplay oddity in the past already.

Comment: Heads-up: I found a little "bug": when version does not exist in the properties, the component version is overwritten with `null`. I'm working on it …

Comment: thanks a lot. Note I would need a first check has($source))
but also a 2nd check has($version) since this one is not always set. I extend my question there.

Comment: thanks a lot! This is completely solving my issue. This jq query transforms a "binary" CycloneDX to a "source" CycloneDX after scanning a debian image with Syft!

Comment: may I ask you to have again a look on my question? My analysis for this one was partially wrong, so I created an additional question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928161/jq-how-to-extract-sub-string-with-pattern-and-rebuild-via-variables

Answer (score 0):

current working solution

```
.components[]|select((.properties[].name=="syft:metadata:source") and (.purl | startswith("pkg:deb/debian")) ) as $comps 
| .name=(.properties[] | select(.name == "syft:metadata:source").value)
| .version=(.properties[] | select(.name == "syft:metadata:sourceVersion").value)
| .purl="pkg:deb/debian/"+(.name)+"@"+(.version)+"?arch=source"
```

It is not yet fully covering my need, but partially...