# jq how to extract sub string with pattern and rebuild via variables?

Tags: jq

Again a jq question as follow up to [How do efficiently replace node values depending on some conditions of sub nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878487/how-do-efficiently-replace-node-values-depending-on-some-conditions-of-sub-nodes/75879104#75879104)

Given the following json, from  CycloneDX format produced by Syft tool over debian:bulleye-slim and alpine docker images.

```
{
    "bomFormat": "CycloneDX",
    "components": [{
            "name": "bsdutils",
            "version": "1:2.36.1-8+deb11u1",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/bsdutils@1:2.36.1-8+deb11u1?arch=amd64&upstream=util-linux%402.36.1-8+deb11u1&distro=debian-11",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:source",
                    "value": "util-linux"
                }, {
                    "name": "syft:metadata:sourceVersion",
                    "value": "2.36.1-8+deb11u1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "curl",
            "version": "7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/curl@7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7?arch=amd64&distro=debian-11"
        }, {
            "name": "libaudit-common",
            "version": "1:3.0-2",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/libaudit-common@1:3.0-2?arch=all&upstream=audit&distro=debian-11",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:source",
                    "value": "audit"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "busybox-binsh",
            "version": "1.35.0-r29",
            "purl": "pkg:apk/alpine/busybox-binsh@1.35.0-r29?arch=x86_64&upstream=busybox&distro=alpine-3.17.2",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:originPackage",
                    "value": "busybox"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for the best jq cmd to give this desired output:

```
{
    "bomFormat": "CycloneDX",
    "components": [{
            "name": "util-linux",
            "version": "2.36.1-8+deb11u1",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/util-linux@2.36.1-8+deb11u1?arch=source",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:source",
                    "value": "util-linux"
                }, {
                    "name": "syft:metadata:sourceVersion",
                    "value": "2.36.1-8+deb11u1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "curl",
            "version": "7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/curl@7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7?arch=amd64&distro=debian-11"
        }, {
            "name": "audit",
            "version": "1:3.0-2",
            "purl": "pkg:deb/debian/audit@1:3.0-2?arch=source",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:source",
                    "value": "audit"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "busybox-binsh",
            "version": "1.35.0-r29",
            "purl": "pkg:apk/alpine/busybox@1.35.0-r29?arch=source",
            "properties": [{
                    "name": "syft:metadata:originPackage",
                    "value": "busybox"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I first took only the debian side and asked about going through the metadata, so got this powerful answer from [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) which answered correctly my oirginal question. Thanks!

```
"syft:metadata:source" as $srcName | "syft:metadata:sourceVersion" as $srcVersion
        |.components[]
        |= . + ( (
          .version as $componentVersion
          | .properties//[]
          | from_entries
          | select(has($srcName))
          | (.[$srcVersion]//$componentVersion) as $version
          | .[$srcName] as $name
          | { $name, $version, purl: "pkg:deb/debian/\($name)@\($version)?arch=source" }
        ) // {}
      )
```

but with the additional output from alpine, this cmd is not correct anymore.
I need to go through the 'upstream=' part of the purl to extract the srcName and srcVersion.

And rebuild the purl by keeping the beginning until the / before the @.

```
.components[].purl | match("/[a-z]+@").offset
```

is giving me the index of the first part, but how do I get the string before that?

I then need to extract the string after the "upstream=", e.g. from

*upstream=util-linux%402.36.1-8+deb11u1&*

util-linux as $srcName
2.36.1-8+deb11u1 as $srcVersion, after skipped '%40' (@) and before the next '&'

How do I combine everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[splits("[=&]|%40")] | .[0,1]` to split and extract the second and third element from your URL.

[Binding](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier%7C...) array elements to variables allows you to use them later in your program:

```
printf '"upstream=util-linux%402.36.1-8+deb11u1&"\n' | jq '
[splits("[=&]|%40")] as [$upstream, $srcName, $srcVersion]
| { $srcName, $srcVersion }
'
```

Alternatively, use [`capture`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#capture(val),capture(regex;flags)) to extract an object with a regular expression:

```
capture("upstream=(?<srcName>.*)%40(?<srcVersion>[^&]*)&")
```

Comment: thanks for putting me in the correct direction. Your answer once again shows that almost everything is possible with jq. However, given the complexity, it appears we will have difficulties to maintain this jq cmd: we may switch to a small python script instead to do the transformation asked by my question.

Answer (score 0):

the question was part of a change request on the syft tool:
https://github.com/anchore/syft/issues/1700

the answer above is correct with jq, but I eventually wrote a python script instead, see in the link above.